# C# bitmask validation

Tags: c#, bitmask

I have a small problem with bitmask validation as below:

```
...
if (BitExist("52","0x20"))
{
 //do something
}
...
...

Private bool BitExist(String value, String key)
{
  //how can i make it return true?
}
```

My main problem is that, the value & key is a string value. Is there an easy way to make this works? I'm very new to this bitmask thingy. Really appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Comment: Parse the strings to numbers and use & operator.

Comment: Why are they strings in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private bool BitExists(string value, string key)
{
    int k = Int32.Parse(key, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    return (Int32.Parse(value) & k) == k;
}
```

What this code snippet does is the following. Inside the bracket the one bit described by key is isolated.

```
 00110100
&00100000
---------
 00100000
```

After that you have you have to determine whether or not the isolated bit is checked:

```
00100000 == 00100000 = true
```

Comment: Except that Int32.parse does not understand `0x20`

Comment: Loose the "0x" and use `int.Parse(key, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);`

Comment: GREAT!!! It works!
Thanks PVitt for the answer and the extra explanation!
Thanks Henk Holterman for providing the key to the solution :)
As for why they are in string is because i read it from XML file.